# SQL Server Always Encrypted

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, always-encrypted

I'm using SQL Server "Always Encrypted" to encrypt data in one table for a few columns.

I need to know is that possible to add "Always Encrypted" to my whole database at once?

Any idea?

Comment: Transparent Data Encryption?

Comment: What do u mean by Transparent Data Encryption? What I need is I need to encrypt all the table in SQL server DB and need to read data from C sharp program.

Comment: Do you want in/out traffic  to be encrypted. i,e,. between client and mssql-server(backend), OR  to scramble the data in the table(s) making the data unreadable?

Comment: Second one. I need to scramble the data in the table(s) making the data unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

Always Encrypted operates at the column level not database or table. Yes, you can encrypt all the columns in al the tables for a entire database. However, there are restriction on types, and limited operation support o encrypted types. My advice is to use AE on very sensitive columns and otherwise use TDE, which is at Rest encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click Database-->Tasks-->Encrypt Columns. 
All table columns can be encrypted at once